# Can I loot the same item multiple times in raid finder?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I recently started doing some raids using the raid finder feature in Mists of Pandaria.

I discovered that I can get items from boss using two different mechanics :

- Automatically winning an item on the first kill of a boss for the week
- Winning an item after using an [Elder Charm of Good Fortune](http://www.wowhead.com/currency=697/elder-charm-of-good-fortune)

However, I was wondering :

- Can I loot the same item multiple times accross multiple weeks ?
- Can I get an item I already looted when I use a charm ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can, it's perfectly possible that you can win the roll and receive the item, and then use an Elder Charm of Good Fortune and receive the same item again. The 'Bonus Loot' system does not check if you already have the item, only that it is relevant to your currently active spec.

In addition, the loot system in general doesn't check what gear you have, it only checks the gear that is relevant to you, meaning that even without the use of Elder Charms, you could get the same item from the boss every time you are eligible to loot it.

Comment: Just as an example: I killed the Stone Guard two weeks ago and nothing dropped. Killed it again that same week and it said I could have gotten the plate boots but was not eligible. Used the Elder Charm for my bonus roll, and got the boots again. Killed it again the week after, and the boots dropped again.

Comment: It's also good to note that if you have more than one spec, say 1 spec for DPS and 1 for tanking/healing, that you can potentially receive a piece of loot for each spec. 1 for your initial roll and another by using an Elder Charm of Good Fortune after swapping specs immediately after the boss was downed.

Comment: Here's another crummy example: two nights ago I won a ring during the normal loot roll. I then decided to roll again and use a Greater Charm because the boss had other gear that I wanted as well. Imagine my surprise (or disappointment rather!) when my 2nd roll landed me the exact same ring. But wait! Irony had my name that evening apparently, because after downing the next boss I had the exact same thing happen with a pair of leggings! I was cussing and laughing all at the same time because of the ironies of dumb luck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to both, I however have not gotten a an item and then had it again through elder charms yet have had multiples, including through elder charms.